# GET-запрос к РФ домену

Tags: python, запрос, get

Требуется отсылать get запросы к сайту, расположенном в рф домене.
Проблема в энкоде, чтобы можно было послать ссылку.

```
from urllib import request
import sys
import codecs

rUrl = u"раз.два/три/четыре/"
encodeUrl = rUrl.encode("idna")
answer = request.urlopen("https://" + encodeUrl)
text = answer.read()
print(text)
```

Ссылка `rUrl = u"раз.два/три/четыре/"` может такой характер носить, а может и `rUrl = u"раз.два/три/?четыре = значение"`

Какие бы я методы не пробовал, получаю одну из этих ошибок:

1. `UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)`
2. `'unknown url type'`
3. `TypeError: must be str, not bytes`

Также еще для авторизации надо использовать `X-ACCESS-KEY`, но до этого я вообще не дошел.

Вопрос - как правильно строить get-запрос в РФ домен с X-ACCESS-KEY?

Comment: Просто используйте punycode вместо кириллического домена.

Comment: Энкодит в punycode нормально, но при выполнении запроса с punycode ссылкой получаю ошибку: `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'timeout'`

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev ну это уже явно проблема в чём-то другом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это не принципиально, попробуйте другую библиотеку. Насколько я могу судить, к примеру, urllib3 таких проблем не имеет.

Импорт

```
import urllib3
```

Сам запрос (сайт первый попавшийся)

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request(
    "GET",
    "https://сайтыобразованию.рф"
)
print(response.data.decode("utf-8"))
```